# What is the determinant of the matrix of $A_{ij} = \gcd(i,j)$ for $i,j$ ranging from $0$ to $n−1$?

Tags: determinant, closed-form

The determinant of the matrix whose entries are $\gcd(i,j)$ for $1≤i,j≤n$ equals $\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)$ where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function: see [A001088 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001088), as well as the paper [“The determinants of GCD matrices” by Zhongshan Li, *Linear Algebra Appl.* **134** (1990) 137–143](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379590900122) and the references it contains regarding the determinant of the matrix whose entries are $\gcd(x_i,x_j)$ for $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ a factor-closed set of positive integers (we get $\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi(x_k)$ up to sign).

**Question:** What about the determinant of the matrix whose entries are $\gcd(i,j)$ for $0≤i,j≤n-1$ instead?  (I.e., labeling rows and columns from $0$ instead of $1$.  Note that the result I just cited doesn't apply.  Also, just to be clear, $\gcd(0,j) = j$ for all $j$.)  Changing the sign, the first values of this determinant are
$$
0, 1, 2, 8, 24, 160, 384, 3456, 16896, 129024\ldots
$$
This sequence is not in the OEIS.  Does it have a simple expression involving the $\varphi(k)$ (it appears to have some resemblance to the $\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi(2k)$, but it's *not* that)?

Comment: Possibly $-\prod_{i = 1}^{n-1} \varphi(i) \cdot \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \varphi(j) \right)$?